# Content Security Policy: The page’s settings observed the loading of a resource at http://127.0.0.1:* (“default-src”). A CSP report is being sent

Tags: jquery, firefox, flask, localhost, content-security-policy

I was planning to create a user-script for a third-party website (Wikipedia). I wanted the javascript part to be lightweight, leaving the heavy lifting to a Python-Flask application to be run on my desktop computer and send back the result as json.

But at the very beginning I got the following error in the console of my Firefox browser:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings observed the loading of a resource at http://127.0.0.1:5000/?test=2 (“default-src”). A CSP report is being sent.
```

What does that mean?

The `jQuery` request was:

```
 jQuery.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:5000/?test=2', {}, function (data) { console.log(data) } )
```

I'm getting back the result as expected, but the error message made me wondering where I did wrong and if there is a better way to do this.

My flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    resp = jsonify({1:2, 3:4})
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = request.headers['Origin']
    return resp
```

I'm using Firefox 64.0b12 (64-bit).

Apparently Chrome 70.0.3538.102 has no issues with the above request and prints no warning/errors.

Answer (score -4):

it mean your json request URL will be reported to Wikipedia, to disable open

```
about:config > security.csp.enable > false
```

read more about Content security Policy [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)

Comment: Do not do that. That will open your browser to vulnerabilities, besides that won't fix anything on prod.

Comment: I do that. Coming from an older firefox instance which did not send data to remote sites, i found myself in the situation where the updated firefox DID send data reports to third parties while devolping a website. Please stop this habit of sending reports around without informing the users about it and giving him a chance to decide over it.